# Не получается сделать выравнивание в header

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Я учу html и css, пока что сильно путаюсь в блоках. Пытаюсь сделать header сайта: с логотипом и панелью навигации. Всё получилось, кроме выравнивания.

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;

    /* Настройки шрифта */
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #81858e;

    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Container
================== */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1600px;
    /* Выравнивание элемента по центру */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Header
================== */
.header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 160px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    
}

.header__inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 35px 0;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Navigation
================== */
.nav {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
}

.nav__link {
    color: #bab8b8;
    margin-left: 70px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color .2s linear;
}

.nav__link:hover {
    color: #3984f3;
}

.nav__sign-in {
    color: #3984f3;
    margin-left: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 3px solid #3984f3 ;
    padding: 13px 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header__inner">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Image"></a>

                <nav class="nav">
                    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Home</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Video</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Destinations</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Booking</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav__sign-in">Sing In</a>
                  </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно не полностью понимаю вопрос,но если проблема в том,что кнопка sing in не ровно, то вот это добавь:

```
.header__inner nav{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```